# Выделение памяти для новой переменной во время работы Assembler

Tags: ассемблер, строки

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как во время работы программы выделить новую переменную.
Проблема в том что, я в цикле считываю строки из edit (графический интерфейс). Текст из edit записываю в переменную.
Соответственно у меня есть массив указателей на строки. И когда я в цикле заношу, то выходит что заношу адрес одной и той же переменной. Подскажите пожалуйста как быть в таком случае?

```
  invoke  GetDlgItemText,[hwnddlg],ID_STR,message,40h
        push eax
        mov al,[strcnt]
        cmp al,cnt
        je eql
        mov [array+eax*4],message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону функций выделения памяти, выбирайте какая больше подходит. Определяйте длину message, выделяйте под это значение память, копируйте туда строку из message, и уже адрес этого куска памяти кладите в массив. Например:

```
; вместо 40h можно и реальный размер строки взять, но особого смысла не вижу:
; не бегамайты, а 64 байта - хороший размер :)
invoke LocalAlloc, LMEM_FIXED or LMEM_ZEROINIT, 40h
; в eax получаем адрес выделенного блока памяти
mov edi, eax
mov esi, message ; или offset message?
mov ecx, размер  ; а вот тут реальный размер строки
push ds
pop es
cld
rep movsb
mov cl, [strcnt] ; ecx уже обнулён
mov [array+ecx*4], eax
```

P.S. А чего это у вас strcnt однобайтовый? Если и так, то тогда уж `movzx eax,[strcnt]`, так  правильней будет.

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста пример , как выделить память , а то что-то не могу найти информации подходящей

Comment: Обновил ответ.